# MONGODB Searching through a 3rd layer json object without knowledge of the containing dictionary

Tags: python, json, mongodb, nosql

My DB goes like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f32e5e2928168864d3219c6"),
    "company_name" : "Automotive",
    "users" :[ {
        "Ali" : {
            "number" 732928191,
            "Mac" : "00A869F32FB8",     
        }
    }]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f32e5e2928168864d3219c6"),
    "company_name" : "medical hospital",
    "users" : [{
        "Erin" : {
            "number" 6063840123,
            "Mac" : "00A859F10DB8", 
            "email": "email@email.com"
        }
       { "Ron" : {
            "number" 2021230303,
            "Mac" : "00B834D133B8", 
            
        }
    }]
}
```

And I'm trying to search for the user who owns, lets say the Mac address 00A859F10DB8 without prior knowledge of his "company_name"  or "name"

Comment: are you sure that `users` is an object?

Comment: No, I'm not sure of the semantics. Can you tell me where you're going with this?

Comment: I was thinking to db.find( {   users.regex: "00B834D133B8"  }     ) But I don't know if thats efficient, or how to set up the regex to pick up all users

Comment: How can we ensure your structure. just need t know whether `users` is an array or object!

Comment: Oh, object for sure. But I'm just building it so I can change it.

Comment: I think if its array, i can help, but i have no idea how to deal with objects within object

Comment: Alright, I can make the change.
How would you find a mac address if users were an array?

Comment: Please edit and let me know the desired output

Comment: I think you need to improve the structure also

Comment: Something like this `{ "company_name" : "Automotive", "users" : [{ "name":"Ali", "number": 732928191, "Mac" : "00A869F32FB8", }] }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219017/discussion-between-ali-elhelali-and-varman).

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I work at Rockset. I see that this question can easily be answered by doing integration with MongoDB and Rockset.

Asking for clarification: What kind of data is this? If this real-time data/ doing analytics,  MongoDB has a partnership with Rockset. With Rockset, you can do full JOINS, Search, and aggregations on deeply nested data - without ever knowing the shape of your data. The EASIEST WAY to solve this ( by easy, not worrying about indexing, setting up shards, and etc) is to use MongoDB as your primary DB and send data to Rockset.

1. On Rockset, give READ permissions to your MongoDB (i.e. if you're on Atlas)
2. Start writing your search query (SQL)
3. You can read this [blog](https://rockset.com/blog/create-apis-for-aggregations-and-joins-on-mongodb-in-under-15-minutes/).
4. Check out this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNMxQU7LK7E)

Again, to iterate, I see that your question is easily answered by using MongoDB + Rockset and doing a simple search SQL query.